# How can I retrieve data from SAP EWM from the query 0WM_MP17_Q0001?

Tags: querying, sap-ewm

I wanted to know how one can retrieve data from the various query tools available in SAP EWM.

I found the queries in the following link: Extended Warehouse Management - SAP Library

The description of the query `0WM_MP17_Q0001` says:

```
0WM_MP17_Q0001



You can use this query to see the number and duration of confirmed warehouse orders by day, week, or month. This allows you to see when typical warehouse trends are changing, and thus take actions such as:
Adjusting work schedules to meet demands
Hiring new workers, or letting existing workers go
Requesting budget for expenses such as extra equipment
```

And I need to retrieve the data for the reasons above.

However, is there a transaction code that I can run to get this report? How can I retrieve this data?

Comment: What link? Which programming environment do you need to extract the data to? Remember that SO is about _programming_ Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already asked this question on SDN and got a response, see your message and [response](https://scn.sap.com/thread/3794291).

This is BI content.